# How do you use StreamWriter to write to a file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

ok so heres the issue, i need to write data to a html file to save it, this format allows me to add anchors and links in which will be needed in many of the files

the names can not be predetermined (they will be files for roleplay characters, and places, 1 file per place or character)

heres the code i have so far

```
private async Task savetest(string name)
    {

        //ok so we get the local storage
        StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        //create the character folder
        var dataFolder = await local.CreateFolderAsync("Character",
            CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        //create the character html
        var file = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync(name+".html",
        CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        //heres where it will get interesting
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(local+"/"+dataFolder+"/"+file))
        { 
            writer.WriteLine("<html><head><title>Character File for " + z.charNameFirst + " " + z.charNameSecond + "</title></head><body>");
            writer.WriteLine("<html><head><title>Character File for " + z.charNameFirst + " " + z.charNameSecond + "</title></head><body>");
            writer.WriteLine("Name: " + z.charNameFirst + " " + z.charNameSecond + " <br>");
            writer.WriteLine("Gender:" + z.charGender+" <br>");
            writer.WriteLine("Race:" + z.charRace + " <br>");
            writer.WriteLine("Class:" + z.charClass + " <br>");
            writer.WriteLine("Gender:" + z.charGender + " <br>");
            writer.WriteLine("<a href=\"#SomeTest\">SomeTest</a><br>");
            writer.WriteLine("<a href=\"#AnotherTest\">AnotherTest</a><br>");
            for (int i = 20; i > 0; i--) 
            { 
                writer.WriteLine("some test text some test text some test text some test text some test text some test text "); 
            }

            writer.WriteLine("<span style=\"font-weight: bold;\"><a name=\"SomeTest\"></a>SomeTest</span><br>");

            for (int i = 20; i > 0; i--) 
            { 
                writer.WriteLine("some test text some test text some test text some test text some test text some test text "); 
            }
            writer.WriteLine("<span style=\"font-weight: bold;\"><a name=\"AnotherTest\"></a>AnotherTest</span><br>");

            for (int i = 20; i > 0; i--) 
            { 
              writer.WriteLine("some test text some test text some test text some test text some test text some test text "); 
            }

            writer.WriteLine("</body></html>");
        }

    }
```

However, there is an issue with the following line:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(local+"/"+dataFolder+"/"+file))
```

The error message says:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.StreamWriter.StreamWriter(System.IO.Stream, System.Text.Encoding)' has some invalid arguments

I don't understand why all the examples I have seen use

```
new StreamWriter(FILENAME)
```

or

```
new StreamWriter(FILENAME,true)
```

for appending data to existing files.

These will be fresh on each run. `FILENAME` in this case should be 
`<Windows Phone App's Local Storage>/Character/<NAMEOFCHARACTER>.html`

I have so many tabs open right now that all say this is the way to do it, but it's just not working and I have no idea why.

NOTE: All of this takes place in the `MainPage.xaml.cs` in the Windows Phone project.

Comment: Try to build the string first, then don't use `StreamWriter` but write it with `FileIO.WriteTextAsync`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701508.aspx

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Qq1WJhh0

same error though cannot convert from string to windoes.storage.istoragefile

Comment: The `StreamWriter(FILENAME)` examples are all Win32; Metro, no I mean WinRT , oops, I mean Windows Store, wait, now it's Universal, sorry, this week it's Windows Universal apps use `StreamWriter(Stream)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

`new StreamWriter(local+"/"+dataFolder+"/"+file)`

with

`new StreamWriter(await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())`

Comment: we then get an error straight after 
"Cannot initialize type 'System.IO.StreamWriter' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'"

also getting Argument 2: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'System.Text.Encoding'

i dont understand why, that is the bolean that controls if the file is overwritten or not, it is optional, but why is it trying to convert it to System.Text.Encoding

Comment: that is really weird. can you re-post the code after the modification?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nMzAyhrR

I see the problem... i think, it wants the filename to be a stream not a string...that just doesnt make any sense to me

Comment: in the newly pasted code, you are missing one bracket. the whole line needs to be

`using (StreamWriter writer = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()))`

Comment: Just to expand the answer: In WinRT (which I'm assuming this is, given the API you are using), you have to abide some rules re. file operations, including not being able to open files directly through string-based file path and name (unlike in Win32 applications). In order to use StreamWriter, you need to "convert" the `StorageFile` object to a stream, which is what the `OpenStreamForWriteAsync()` extension method is for.

If this is not a WinRT application, don't use the Windows.Storage namespace at all, switch to good old System.IO and you'll be fine.

Comment: its a windows phone application (8.1 and above), it will be a universal app when finished but for now im working purely on the phone side of things

Comment: In that case, you are indeed using WinRT API. In those, you can not instantiate a `StreamWriter` from a filename, you have to pass a `Stream` object (which is what the error message you provided says as well).

Comment: but the OpenStreamForWriteAsync() does not appear to work at all, as mentioned in the error above (even with the missing brackets)

im thinking i need to find a whole new way to do this

error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IO.Stream' to 'System.IO.StreamWriter'

Comment: Sorry - my bad: In the second answer (4 answers above) it was supposed to say `using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()))` (I forgot the new StreamWriter part :) )

Comment: my bad too i should of noticed that (been a long day)

That seems to have worked, thank you...now i just need to find where on the phone it is actually putting the files (seems different to android)